# regex:finding a forbidden char in python code

Tags: python, regex, interpreter

I need to use a regex will determine if a single line of python code contains an illegal char
'$'. But its allowed to appear in a comment or as part of a string. 
Meaning:

```
"legal char $" illegal $ #legal $
```

The above line should fail because it has a $ that isn't part of a string or a comment.
If I remove it, and get

```
"legal char $" legal #legal $
```

This line should pass.

Comment: Don't forget about multi-line string literals (using backslash as the continuation character, or enclosed in `"""` or `'''`).

Comment: aix, the line is a single line, not part of a multiline string or anything.
Ansari:
I tried this
"[^$]*(:*\'?.*\')*(?<!#)$"

Comment: "a single line of python code" - neither of the lines you posted are valid python code.

Comment: they are examples, the check if its valid code happen later.

I just need to see if the char $ doesn't appear outside of a string or a comment.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If it's for security it's almost certainly bad idea :) It's also really hard to do this as regex ... consider multiple string literals on one line, different quote, etc.

Comment: You have a parsing problem; please address it properly, by tokenizing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illegal: Check for a `.*$.*#?` after creating a temporary string by using re.sub to replace \".*?\" in the line with an empty string.

Legal: not Illegal :) or `[^$]*#?`

Comment: great idea! I was so focused on creating a single regex.
divide and conquer wins.